# I majored in applied math in college and I can't figure out this problem...Why does my calculator say error when I try to multiply a 2x2 matrix by 3x3

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 2x2 Matrix and a 3x3 Matrix and everytime I try to multiply them in my calculator, it just says error. Why is this happening?

Comment: (3x3) times (2x2) is undefined

Comment: This is a delightful question!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to review matrix multiplication [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). In short, the number of columns in the *first* matrix must equal the number of rows in the *second* matrix in order for multiplication to be defined on the matrices. A $n \times r$ matrix multiplied by a $r \times k$ matrix equals a $n \times k$ matrix.

Comment: Think about how the $ij$th element of $AB$ is computed: it’s (essentially) the dot product of the $i$th row of $A$ with the $j$th column of $B$. So the rows of $A$’rows and the columns of $B$’s must be the same size.